# Чтобы персонаж,отыграв своё,больше не подгружался на сцене после каждой ее перезагрузки

Tags: c#, unity3d

В игре есть сцена в виде кухни. В какой-то момент игрок туда заходит и там встречает персонажа,у них случается диалог,после этого игрок выходит в другое место и мне нужно чтобы когда игрок будет возвращаться,того персонажа там уже не было и он не подгружался вообще после каждой загрузки сцены-кухни в дальнейшем.

Comment: Если Вам нужно именно это, то конечно делайте. Кто ж запрещает. А **вопрос**-то в чем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тогда проще использовать несколько иную логику. Если условие НЕ выполняется, то персонаж загружается и ставится в нужную точку.

Например, есть у вас какой-то журнал квестов - выполненных и взятых. Пишете скрипт, который умеет спаунить вашего квестового персонажа и знает какое условие должно выполняться. Каждый раз при запуске сцены этот скрипт будет проверять условие и если оно выполняется (например, задание этого персонажа не сдано), то скрипт создаёт в нужной точке персонажа.